# Using regex to search for a string pattern within a file before a , and after

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a large log file and I want to certain information from that file.
I am trying to use grep and regex to pull the data but I am not getting anywhere.

The format of a single line is:

```
000.00.000.00,000,xxx,xxx.xxx.xxx,xxx
```

zero = numbers and x = a char

But I want everything after the second ',' and before the last ','

I have been trying

```
grep [[a-zA-Z].\.[a-zA-Z].\.[a-zA-Z]]
```

and all sort but I have not managed to get it

I am hoping to get just:

```
','xxx.xxx.xxx','
```

but without the `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Perl:

```
perl -ape 's/^.+?[a-z]+,([^,]+).*$/$1/i' file
```

**Output:**

```
xxx.xxx.xxx
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/              # substitute
  ^             # beginning of line
  .+?           # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  [a-z]+        # 1 or more letters
  ,             # a comma
  ([^,]+)       # group 1, 1 or more non comma
  .*            # 0 or more any character but newline
  $             # end of line
/               # replace with
  $1            # content of group 1
/i              # case insensitive
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with `sed`, could you please try following(based on your description).

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,].*\)\(.*\)/'"'"','"'"'\3'"'"','"'"'/'  Input_file
```

Here I am using `sed`'s capability of holding matched regex values into memory which we could use during substitution.

Comment: Yea I will give that a go

Comment: yea that worked but it added " ',' " to the end of the string and after

Comment: @trigster, glad that it helped you, give it sometime and when you have few answers, you could select any answer out of them as correct one too, cheers.

Comment: Sorry, that did not work, i was abit hasty, it still added everything before the after the commna, but it did remove the digits

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

```
    import re
    str = "000.00.000.00,000,xxx,xxx.xxx.xxx,xxx"
    matched = re.findall('.*([a-zA-Z]{3}\.[a-zA-Z]{3}\.[a-zA-Z]{3}),[a-zA-Z]{3}$',str)
    print(matched)
```